# Sharing a Steam library over the network with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares

I have a desktop computer with Windows 10 which has enough space for a large Steam library. A friend of mine will come over in a couple of weeks with an ultrabook that lacks the disk space to install a few hundred GB of games. The current workaround is a USB 3.0 stick where he has a second Steam library on it.

Since the network here is Gigabit, it should be possible with reasonable speeds (125 MB/s) to just transfer all those files via the network as needed. This will not scale with many people, of course, but for certain games it might be reasonable.

On Linux, I knew how to do this:

- Create an NFS share of like `/Steam/Common`
- Mount that into `/Steam/Common` on the other computer

How could I do this on Windows? My experience with shared folders is from Windows 98 and XP where one can just create a read-only share with some name and no password. Since Windows Vista there seems to be this home network workgroup going on which I have never bothered to set up. Also when trying to have a share without a password on a passwordless account, there is no way to connect with an empty password string.

How would I go about creating a read-only share and let somebody else connect to it such that they can use that as an additional Steam library?

Comment: Just do something like this, [Building a local Steam caching server to ease the bandwidth blues](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/01/building-a-local-steam-caching-server-to-ease-the-bandwidth-blues/), but you would need a similar library in order for that to work well.

Comment: Solves the download problem, does not solve the problem of lacking disk space.

Comment: I don't consider the "lacking disk space" a problem that can be answered by this community.  Steam also allows you to move specific games in your library.  This means you can use external storage locations.

Comment: Yes, and I'd like to use a network drive as this external location. That should be possible, right?

Comment: This is a good read: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/run-your-steam-library-from-a-nas-break-a-leg-challenge-update/107912

Answer (score 0):

select your desktop liabrary folder and share it over your network as lun network drive (software available to do  that)

on your ultrabook in steam add a liabrary location and locate your shared folder on network

restart and you are good to go

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but it’s a bit vague.  Can you describe what to do, step by step?  What menu, what button, what command, what option, etc? … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.